# GDI+ Window preventing Shutdown

Tags: c#, gdi+, windows-server-2003

I am developing for a Server 2003 with C# and .NET Framework 2.0

As long as the program runs, I can't shutdown my machine. Nothing happens, but when alt+tabbing I can see a window called "GDI+ Window". As soon as I close my program, I can shut down the computer properly.

However, on my other computers (windows XP professional, windows 8, windows 8.1) it doesn't happen.

The program pulls data from a database and sends them to the internet, so I have a Thread running in the background. Could that be a problem?

The code in the main class is the following:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool run = true;
    //AutoStart autoS = new AutoStart();
    int interval;
    //LogFileBuilder lfboom = new LogFileBuilder(true);*/

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        /*OpenOnce();
        //autoS.EintragHinzufügen();
        WriteMe();
        LogFileBuilder lfb = new LogFileBuilder();
        lfb.writeLine("Programm gestartet");
        new Thread(Durchführung).Start();*/
    }
}
```

Of course there are other methods and event handlers in the form, but they are not relevant, since they are not called, when reproducing this problem. As you can see, I have commented out my whole code except for the InitializeComponents(), but still, the problem occurs.

Steps for reproduction:
1. Open the program
2. Shutdown the Server
3. Nothing happens, except for the new "GDI+ Window" in the alt+tab list, which isn't openable

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943453

Comment: I suggest reconsidering whether you need to display a UI for a program that runs in the background and pulls information from a database and sends it to the Internet. If you don't create any kind of UI, you won't initialize GDI+, and this window won't be created.

Comment: I thought about the UI, but it is important, since I have to change some data frequently, which is so much more convenient and I can display information structured. I inserted the example code from your link, but I get a TypeLoadException. Additional information:  The Type "MyProject.Form1" from the Assembly "MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"could not be loaded, because the method "SetForegroundWindow" does not have an implementation (no RVA). (freely translated by me)

Comment: If the UI is just for configuration, I'd separate out the UI from the normal mode. Perhaps using a command line argument, e.g. `/config`. That would cause the UI to appear, otherwise running the app normally would not display a UI. That would allow it to run in the background even when there's no desktop available.

Comment: But don't I have to close the UI again for being able to shut the PC down? That is actually a really big problem for me, since it will be installed on multiple computers and some people won't think about closing the program before shutting the PC down, so it has to be 100% stable.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23638290/gdi-window-preventing-shutdown#comment36305113_23638290) there is known condition when the GDI+ subsystem initializes and then remains the foreground window. The solution offered in the [KB article 943453](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943453/a-gdi-window-may-appear-when-launching-an-application-on-an-empty-desktop-or-start-a-screensaver) is to explicitly set the foreground window once your Main form loads, like so:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    // tell the runtime to use the user32.dll for implementation of the next method
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    // what is returned by this method
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    // the methed to call in User32
    // upper/lower case is important
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(this.Handle);
    }
}
```

In the comments you claim you tried that but were confronted with a typeload exception:

> System.TypeLoadException was unhandled
>   Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Could not load type 'App.Form1' from assembly 'App, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because the method 'SetForegroundWindow' has no implementation (no RVA).

That is caused because `SetForegroundwindow`doesn't have the `[Dllimport]` attribute applied. I can repro that exception by commenting the line with `[Dllimport]`. Without that your code will compile but because the method `SetForegroundWindow` will not have any implementation the runtime refuses to load your type, hence the exception.

In a technical sense the RVA stands for *Relative Virtual Address* and is an offset to the baseaddress of the module. Looking up an items RVA and adding it to the baseaddress will return the item (method, data, etc) start pointer. If there is nothing to lookup as there is nothing to execute, the module can't be safely executed. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx for more background.

So to sum it up, the following code when called

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

will execute [this unmanaged method in the WinAPI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ms633539(v=vs.85).aspx)